# Comparing a CASE result to another CASE SQL Command - Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sqlcommand

I am trying to combine to compare a result from a case to clean up some data. For

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(X)), 1,1)) = 0
    THEN UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(X, CHARINDEX(' ', X)+1, LEN(X) - CHARINDEX(' ', X)))))
    ELSE X
END XCU
CASE 
     WHEN XCU LIKE '%A%' OR '%B%' THEN 'Y'
     ELSE X
   END 
FROM XTable
```

The first case works perfect yeilds XCU, I then want to compare XCU to find keywords and result a general Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is by using nested sql query

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN xcu LIKE '%A%' 
               OR xcu like '%B%' THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE 'x' 
       END, 
       xcu 
FROM  (SELECT CASE 
                WHEN Isnumeric(Substring(Ltrim(Rtrim(x)), 1, 1)) = 0 THEN Upper( 
                Ltrim(Rtrim(Substring(x, Charindex(' ', x) + 1, Len(x) - 
                            Charindex(' ', x) 
                            )))) 
                ELSE 'x' 
              END XCU 
       FROM   xtable)  A
```

Comment: I used your exact code but I get -- An express of non-boolean type specified in a context where condition is expected near 'Then'

Comment: GREAT, it worked, can you explain what the A is at the very end? I am a newb at SQL -- Thank you @pradeep